# component Updated without even a call to shouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue with my react app: In a parent component I have `shouldComponentUpdate()` returning `false`. As expected the `shouldComponentUpdate()` of child components is not called. However the `componentDidUpdate()` of the child components is called (but not the one of the parent component). It causes performance issus, and I would like child component not to be updated.

I've checked that:

- Each child component is still the same : the key does not change and the constructor is not called again.
- I do not make use of `forceUpdate()` anywhere

Does anyone have an idea of what could go wrong ?

Comment: Please provide some codes to understand more correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In case the answer can help others : it is a consequence of the use of contexts : whenever the value changes, everything component using the context gets updated no matter what.